# How a consensus algorithm is implemented in a private Blockchain network ( ethereum )?

Tags: consensus, clique, mastering-ethereum, geth-clique

How to implement a new custom consensus algorithm in a network.

Comment: The general question to add a new consensus algorithm was asked previously http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/28576/plug-new-consensus-into-go-ethereum-geth, but it was not answered in full yet. Since geth is always changing it is complicated to create a guide that might be obsolete in short time.

Answer (score 1):

How to implement a new custom consensus algorithm in a network?

> As per your question you need to first fork private ethereum
>   blockchain([go ethereum](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum)) and need to modify [consensus.go](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/consensus/consensus.go) file
>   as per your custom requirements.

Hope this will help you.